# Get div's width for p5.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, p5.js

I'm learning on my own JavaScript so I'm doing something like a website using p5.js

The thing is that a `div` holding my canvas for p5.js and I want it to be responsive. In this `canvas`, I do have an object that needs the `div` width and height to be constructed.

Problem is that I don't know how to get this information. I tried jQuery but I don't know how to extract value out of a jQuery function and I'm don't know if it's an excessive way to do it.

```
//--------------------------constant--------------------------------------------
//Canvas

const DROPNUMBER = 1500;

//--------------------------classe---------------------------------------------
function Drop(width, heigth) {

  //declaring and setting drop's attribute
  this.spawn = function(width) {

    //size and position
    this.x = Math.random() * -width*1.5;
    this.y = Math.random() * heigth;
    this.size = Math.random() * 20 ;

    //color
    this.colorR = 138 + Math.random() * 50;
    this.colorV = 43 + Math.random() * 50;
    this.colorB = 226 + Math.random() * 50;
    this.colorA = Math.random() * 127 +50;

    //speed and landing
    this.speed = Math.random();
    this.hasLanded = false;
  }

  //call func to set the attribute
  this.spawn(width);

  //make the drop falls
  this.fall = function() {
    //if the drop can fall
    if (this.x < width) {
      this.x = this.x + this.speed;
      this.speed = this.speed + 0.01;

      //if the drop did land
      if (this.y + this.size > width && this.hasLanded == false) {
        this.hasLanded = true;
      }
    }

    //if the drop did fall
    else {
      this.spawn(width);
    }
  }

  //display the drop
  this.display = function() {
    noStroke();
    //Some kind of purple color
    fill(this.colorR, this.colorV, this.colorB, this.colorA);
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size)
  }
}


//--------------------------setup---------------------------------------------

function setup() {
  clientHeight = document.getElementById('header').clientHeight;
  clientWidth = document.getElementById('header').clientWidth;
  canvas = createCanvas(clientWidth, clientHeight);
  canvas.parent('sketch-holder');
    window.canvas = canvas;
}


//-------------------------Variable---------------------------------------------

  var n = DROPNUMBER;
  var drops = new Array();


  //creating an array of drop for the rain
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    //800 800 is height and the width that i want to change !
    drops.push(new Drop(800,800)); 

  }

//--------------------------draw------------------------------------------------
function draw() {
  background(48, 64, 96);
  //each drop
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    //Make them falling
    drops[i].fall();
    //display the result
    drops[i].display();

  }
}
```

The code is just showing that drops ( the object that needs height and width) are being constructed out of draw or setup function.
I did search already on Stack Overflow to this kind of problem too.

Comment: it's actually not clear what element you need to obtain the width for--you already get the height and width of your header tag using the method I discuss a little below. Do you need to get the height and width of something else? What is your trouble exactly?

Comment: I need to get the width and the height of my canvas but out of the draw() or the setup() function. I think it's a constant that you can get inside of them thanks to p5 but not outside

Comment: how about `window.canvas.clientWidth`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use JQuery for this. Take a look at the [P5.dom library](https://p5js.org/reference/#/libraries/p5.dom) that provides a bunch of functionality for manipulating HTML elements in P5.js.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but here's a simple example. If we have a `div` on the page with and ID of `myId`, then to get its width we could use P5.dom to do this:

```
var myDiv = select('myId');
var myWidth = myDiv.style.width;
console.log('width: ' + myWidth);
```

Comment: Hum i'd like to have the width out of the setup() or draw() function. Does "select" can be use out of these ? Thanks !

Comment: @OgL0C Yes, you can use the `select()` function from inside the `setup()` or `draw()` functions. What happened when you tried?

Comment: Let's sum up. I want my object to be created out of these functions because i handle them in the draw() function. So if i want an array of these objects it must be created out of the draw() function so i doesn't get re-created at each draw() call no ? Problem is that if i call select out of draw() function it says me "select is not defined". I'm sure i'm lacking a lot of things sorry

Comment: @OgL0C You need to call it after `setup()` has been called. You can't have P5.js code outside of functions.

Comment: Just a note to remind you if you are using p5 in "instance" mode, you need to add the instance name to select(), as in sketch.select().

Answer (score 1):

use a regular DOM js it's worked:

```
let b = document.getElementById("parentElement");
let w = b.clientWidth;
let h = b.clientHeight;
console.log(w, h);
```

Comment: For me this works for the width but not the height.

Answer (score 0):

To get the width of an element in JavaScript, you can select that element using `document.querySelector()`. Any CSS selector is a valid first argument to that function. E.g. the following will select the `<body>` tag:

```
document.querySelector('body')
```

Once you have an element selected, you can get it's width by accessing the `clientWidth` property. E.g. the following tells you the width of the `<body>` tag:

```
document.querySelector('body').clientWidth
```

So just replace `body` with a CSS selector for the element you want to select.